# Hibernate 5 and Transaction rollback detection with interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

We had a Hibernate Interceptor that was intercepting `afterTransactionCommit` and checking the Transaction for `wasCommited()`, but we recently upgraded to Hibernate 5.0.7.Final, and hibernate 5 no longer has this call, and when we call the `getStatus()` function we only every seem to get either `ACTIVE` or `NOT_ACTIVE` regardless of the transaction state.

I looked at `afterTransactionBegin` and the transaction is marked `ACTIVE`, which is expected, and in `beforeTransactionCompletion` it is still marked `ACTIVE`, which again, is expected, but then in `afterTransactionCommit` it is marked `NOT_ACTIVE`, which doesn't make a sense to me. I would have expected one of `COMMITTED, ROLLED_BACK, FAILED_COMMIT`. I get this no matter if the transaction state, even if I throw an exception which causes a rollback, I still don't see any status other than `NOT_ACTIVE`.

The reason we are looking for this information is to determine if we need to post some messages to a queue. Basically if the transaction wasn't committed don't post. As of right now with Hibernate 5 I can't seem to find out how to determine programatically if the transaction was successful or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate 5 removed the ability to detect rollback in it's interceptor.  Instead one can capture that transaction was rolled back and infer a rollback if it was not committed.

For example:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
.
.
.

private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> wasCommited = new ThreadLocal();

@Override
public void beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
    // not called for rollback
    wasCommited.set(Boolean.TRUE);
}


@Override
public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {

    if ( !Boolean.TRUE.equals(wasCommited.get()) ) {
        try {
           // handle transaction rolled back
        }
        finally {
            wasCommited.set(null);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify what your issue is and provide some examples (if possible) of what you would expect to happen.

Comment: @Tim Do you also know what happens, if the commit acually fails?

Comment: I checked that this sollution doesn't work, if the commit itself fails. In that case `afterTransactionCompletion` sees commit, that didn't happen.

Comment: @vnov you are correct, does not get called on failed commit.  Saw your solution below.  For failed commit w/  JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl afterCompletion is also not called. :(

Comment: That is to say, Synchronization.afterCompletion is also not called on failed commit, so neither solutions works.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring transaction, you can use a `TransactionSynchronization` for this kind of things. For example :

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){
           void afterCommit() {
                ..
           }
});
```

See [TransactionSynchronizationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully utilized [`javax.transaction.Synchronization`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Synchronization.html) which can be registered with the transaction and receives correct status. It can be registered using the Hibernate Interceptor:

```
  @Override
  public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {
    tx.registerSynchronization(new Synchronization() {
      @Override
      public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        // Here the status is correct
      }
    });
  }
```

---

**Edit:**

Unfortunattely, this solution works only, if the commit or rollback succeedes, otherwise the callback is not called. I must have had wrong test initially. You can see that in the code of `JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.TransactionDriverControlImpl`.

Answer (score 1):

After some struggle I ended up with [vnov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523461/302517) to the Hibernate 5 solution (to replace the now missing `org.hibernate.Transaction.wsComitted()` method). This answer elaborates more in depth on the problem solution. I am using `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor` via Spring AOP.

```
  @Before("bean(emptyInterceptor)
      && execution(public * *.afterTransactionBegin(..))
      && args(tx)")
  protected void afterTransactionBegin(org.hibernate.Transaction tx) {
    tx.registerSynchronization(new javax.transaction.Synchronization() {
      @Override
      public void beforeCompletion() {
      }
      @Override
      public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        /*
          status is e.g. javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_COMMITTED
          do my stuff here,
          i.e. move here the body of the
          afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction) method
        */
      }
    });
  }
```

In the
`JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.TransactionDriverControlImpl` class source I see that:

- If the commit fails, the RuntimeException will be caught and the transaction will be rolled back. So the `Synchronization.afterCompletion(int)` method will then be called with the `status == Status.STATUS_UNKNOWN` in case of a successful rollback.
- **If the rollback fails with an exception, the `Synchronization.afterCompletion(int)` method will not be called at all.**

**Edit (2021-11-24)**

As we needed a solution that also considers possibility of the rollback failure, we came up with this solution (the `afterTransactionCompletion` method is called also after the rollback failed).

```
  private ThreadLocal<Boolean> txCommitted = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> false);

  @Before("bean(emptyInterceptor)
      && execution(public * *.afterTransactionBegin(..))
      && args(tx)")
  protected void afterTransactionBegin(org.hibernate.Transaction tx) {
    tx.registerSynchronization(new Synchronization() {
      @Override
      public void beforeCompletion() {
      }
      @Override
      public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        txCommitted.set(status == Status.STATUS_COMMITTED);
      }
    });
  }

  @Before("bean(emptyInterceptor)
      && execution(public * *.afterTransactionCompletion(..))
      && args(tx)")
  protected void afterTransactionCompletion(org.hibernate.Transaction tx) {
    if (txCommitted.get()) {
      /* do my on-commit stuff here */
    } else {
      /* do my otherwise stuff here */
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm writing this comment to ask if this is still how you see the solution, if you've changed anything since writing this. I'm working on a similar problem myself and this stackoverflow item seems to quite literally be the only thing going into it.

Comment: Yes, I am still using this approach since I wrote the answer. Seems to work fine for our use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't get this to work for my setup, though the accepted answer, by Tim Dugan with the ThreadLocal, seems to work at first glance. Though I haven't done far-reaching tests on this yet.

Comment: Coming back later to say: I tried this again and now it's working. I probably didn't check for the correct status. I see now you mention it's `Status.STATUS_UNKNOWN` and I went into the source code and found that too. If there's a rollback, it's just set to that... not exactly granular, but ok I guess...