# Hibernate 5 transaction status not being tracked?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Upgrading Hibernate 4.3 to 5.0(and newer versions to come later), I've run into an issue where the transaction passed to `afterTransactionCompletion` doesn't seem to be the same transaction object that executed the actual commit.

The transaction status simply remains `NOT_ACTIVE`.

I believe it is probably the same issue as in this ticket: [Hibernate 5 and Transaction rollback detection with interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612433/hibernate-5-and-transaction-rollback-detection-with-interceptor)

Yet all answers indicate that their solution does not work in all situations.

I also see the accepted answer saying:

> Hibernate 5 removed the ability to detect rollback in it's interceptor.

Is this truly the case? There's no way to keep track of what happened to a transaction? Except through some kind of synchronization that can still fail if there's an exception, possibly leaving databases in an inconsistent state?

I've read the transaction part in the migration document: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#transactions

But nothing mentioned there was ever explicitly defined. So I don't know if I need to do something with `coordinator_class`

Does anybody know more about this and how to properly fix this?